# I'm Trying to subscribe from mqtt broker using C# Application

Tags: c#, mqtt

Hi i published a message from paho client to MQTT broker and want to subscribe that message using that topic ; my problem is when debugger comes to the line client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived; it is not executing the method and moving to the next line.

I use hive mqtt broker and c# Form Application with M2MQTT libraries added.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// including the M2Mqtt Library
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MqttClient client = new MqttClient("192.168.43.51");
  client.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1;
  byte code = client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  ushort msgIds = client.Subscribe(new string[] { @"Factory1\Sensor1" },
                    new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
  textBox1.Text = "";
  client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
}
void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
  {
    textBox1.Text += "Received = " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message) + " 
    on topic " + e.Topic + "\r\n";
  });
}
```

I want to get the published message in the text box. will you people help me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is when debugger comes to the line client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived; it is not executing the method and moving to the next line.

This line should not execute the method as it is only wiring up an event handler. Instead, the code in the event handler `client_MqttMsgPublishReceived` will be invoked when the `MqttClient` class raises the `MqttMsgPublishReceived` event (on receiving an MQTT message).

You can see this by adding a breakpoint to the `client_MqttMsgPublishReceived` function and publishing a message to the `Factory1\Sensor1` topic. You can use a separate MQTT client to publish this message. (Note that the MQTT topic separator is a forward slash '/' so you will need to publish to a topic with a backslash.)

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#event-handlers for an overview of how to subscribe to events.